# Stop wordpress from prettify URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I am using ajax to filter taxonomy archive's results by multiple terms.
The "initial" url is `http://mysite.dev/product-categoty/term1/`

I do update the URL struture on ajax response to something like:
`http://mysite.dev/product-category/term1/?my_prefix_product_category=term2`

If i access the url above directly, WP will rewrite it to:

`http://mysite.dev/product-category/term1/term-children-1/term2`.

Is there any way to prevent this from happen for this specific pattern?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using WP Admin AJAX or better yet the REST API rather than hacking AJAX responses into your template?

Comment: Hi Tom. What do you mean by 'using WP Admin AJAX'?

Comment: there's a dedicated API for AJAX, you shouldn't need to hack AJAX into a template via URL parameters https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins although I'd recommend using the REST API to fetch data instead

Answer (score 0):

The website below gives you some know how in how you can managed to achieve what you want.

https://www.bloggersignal.com/stop-wordpress-from-guessing-urls/